# How does C++ know the container class has a push_back function?

Tags: c++

When I look at `std::back_insert_iterator` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator

It says the container's push_back method will be called. How does it know if the container has a method of push_back? Does it require a class that extends any virtual class and where is it defined?

Comment: Because it compiles successfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How does it know if the container has a method of push_back?

It doesn't. You'll get a compile error if you try to use it on a container that doesn't have `push_back`.

> Does it require a class that extends any virtual class and where is it defined?

No, it just requires a class that defines it. In general, templates don't use dynamic polymorphism via virtual functions; they just require the code they contain (like `container.push_back(thing)`) to be valid after argument substitution.

Answer (score 6):

> It says the container's push_back method will be called. How does it know if the container has a method of push_back? Does it require a class that extends any virtual class and where is it defined?

No, `push_back()` is usually not a virtual method.

The `std::back_insert_iterator` is a template, which is going to call `push_back()` on the passed object. It the method is missing, you are going to get a compile error.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't magically know this to be true. Instead, it fails to compile if it doesn't find such a function.

The operations (assignment in this case) which should call `push_back` are written using `push_back` and if the given container does not have a function with that name, the invocation of that function simply won't compile.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about templates (the container sent as an template) then the compiler will try to expand the template and if it doesn't find the method, it will simply fail. The templates are checked at compile time, so the compile will inform you that a container doesn't have the method you requested...

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't know, you should know it. You have to pass the container which has `push_back` to `std::back_insert_iterator`. Otherwise, it will cause to compile errors.

For example, if you use it for a `set` you will get this error:

> 'class std::set' has no member named 'push_back'

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not need to extend a class.

`std::back_insert_iterator` is a template; and the compiler will find out if the type you're trying to use the template on has this method or not when he instantiates it.

I think this type of requiring a certain interface via templates is called an *Implicit Interface* (although I can't find a definitive reference at this point) - in contrast to *explicit* interfaces exhibited by deriving from a certain (possibly abstract) class.

Answer (score 1):

It is a templatised class.

It will generate the code at compile time. In the compile time, it will look for `push_back` function in container. If there is not `push_back`, it will not compile.